# jQuery not working while setting up a new site

Tags: jquery

I am building a little hobby site for fans of a soccer team, and I am trying to add some jQuery, and I can not seem to get the jQuery to get triggered.

I made a submit button inside a form in the right hand column that is supposed to call a jQuery function when clicked, but it isn't calling the jQuery function.

I figured it would be easier to link to the site than paste a bunch of convoluted code here.

Would anyone know why the jQuery is not being called?

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery isn't compatible with soccer sites

Comment: @zerkms lol man :) can't believe how many upvotes that anti-soccer message got so quickly :)

Comment: @zerkms Only in locale="us"; jQuery thinks "football" means something else.

Comment: Plus one upvote for funny messages.  Didn't realize a soccer question would bring out the humor in SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code with [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Otherwise, you'll try to bind elements that were **not yet loaded** by the browser:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#search_fans").click(function () {
    alert('2');
  }
});
```

Which is also equivalent to (and less verbose):

```
$(function () {
  $("#search_fans").click(function () {
    alert('2');
  }
});
```

Comment: of course, the document ready!!! Thanks! I will accept in 10 min when SO allows me to do that.